# Exclude certain selections from a drop down list ASP

Tags: asp-classic, html-select, dropdown

I'm working on a ASP (Within the payment gateway). The options in the drop down at being pulling in from a database. I can't touch the database so have to attack the matter from the code.

Here is the value name that I need to exclude `_01BM(Q)`

Here is the code for the drop down.

```
<select name="programgroup" onchange="onProgramGroup()">                    
<% Call buildDropDownList(strProgramGroupCode, rsProgramGroup, "ProgramGroupCode", "ProgramGroupDescription", False)%>
</select>
```

I would really appreciate any help on this guys.

Here is the code for the method:

```
Sub buildDropDownList(strCurrentSelection, objListData, strCodeName, strDescriptionName, blnIncludeOther)
    If Not objListData.BOF Then
        objListData.MoveFirst
    End If
    While Not objListData.EOF
        Response.Write "<option value='" & objListData(strCodeName) & "' "
        If StrComp(strCurrentSelection, objListData(strCodeName),1) = 0 then
            Response.Write "selected"
        End If
        Response.Write ">" & objListData(strDescriptionName) & "</option>" & VbCrLf
        objListData.MoveNext
    Wend

    if blnIncludeOther then
        Response.Write "<option value='<Other>' "
        If strCurrentSelection <> "" and InStr(1, "<Other>", strCurrentSelection) = 1 then
            Response.Write "selected"
        End If
        Response.Write ">Other</option>" & VbCrLf
    end if
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to post the code of `buildDropDownList`.

Comment: Thank you Im still tring to locate that function at the moment Im looking in the include.asp file but nowhere does it reference ProgramGroupCode

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change the method building the drop down. Since you did not provide us with the code for it, I'll give you a skeleton, and can use it to change your actual code.

To make it more generic and less ugly, better pass the value(s) to exclude to the method, as an array, instead of hard coding them in there.

So, the method should look like this:

```vbs
Sub buildDropDownList(strProgramGroupCode, rsProgramGroup, someParamHere, anotherParam, boolParam, arrValuesToExclude)
    Dim excludedValuesMapping, x
    Set excludedValuesMapping = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For x=0 To UBound(arrValuesToExclude)
        excludedValuesMapping.Add(LCase(arrValuesToExclude(x)), True)
    Next

    '...unknown code here...

    Do Until rsProgramGroup.EOF
        strCurrentValue = rsProgramGroup(valueFieldName)
        If excludedValuesMapping.Exists(LCase(strCurrentValue)) Then
            'value should be excluded, you can do something here, but not write it to browser
        Else  
            strCurrentText = rsProgramGroup(textFieldName)
            Response.Write("<option value=""" & Replace(strCurrentValue, """", "&quot;") & """>" & strCurrentText & "</option>")
        End If
        rsProgramGroup.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

And to use it:

```
<% Call buildDropDownList(strProgramGroupCode, rsProgramGroup, "ProgramGroupCode", "ProgramGroupDescription", False, Array("_01BM(Q)"))%>
```

Now having your code, and if you don't want to make it generic, you can also ignore specific values by having such code in the `buildDropDownList` sub:

```
Dim currentCodeValue
While Not objListData.EOF
    currentCodeValue = objListData(strCodeName)
    If (UCase(currentCodeValue)<>"_04GIDBM") And _
        (UCase(currentCodeValue)<>"_05GIDFM") And _ 
        (UCase(currentCodeValue)<>"_08EXHRM") And _ 
        (UCase(currentCodeValue)<>"_10EXMKT") And _ 
        (UCase(currentCodeValue)<>"_12EXTTH") And _ 
        (UCase(currentCodeValue)<>"_17EXHSC") Then
        Response.Write "<option value='" & currentCodeValue & "' "
        If StrComp(strCurrentSelection, currentCodeValue, 1) = 0 then
            Response.Write "selected"
        End If
        Response.Write ">" & objListData(strDescriptionName) & "</option>" & VbCrLf
    End If
    objListData.MoveNext
Wend
```

This will just skip any records with such values, and will not output a drop down option for them.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort but I wont lie I'm a bit lost on this one now as the buildDropDownList section of the code is something I'm trying to figure. For the record I agree the code is very messy but never the less I have to keep on this one until a solution can be found.

Comment: This is the solution, @user2219472 - if you can't figure how to change the  method post what you have in there and maybe we can guide you what to change in there.

Comment: Dear Shadow Wizard, Thank you truly and yes I'm still struggling with this one. Could you maybe give some step as to what you want me to supply. Sadly I cant post the entire page here ;-)

Comment: @user2219472 only the code for a method called "buildDropDownList" should be enough.

Comment: I just added what I think we looking for in my orginal post. It after update and i think its what you want. i9t was found in an include.asp file. Please let me know if its not correct. Thank you mate

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the code in the include.asp file but cant see a change in the drop selection. I need to now remove 6 options from the drop down. what should I do next sir!

Comment: @user2219472 what are the exact values of those 6 options? Are you sure "_01BM(Q)" is one them?

Comment: _04GIDBM  _05GIDFM _08EXHRM _10EXMKT _12EXTTH _17EXHSC  these are all the exact values that I see when I look at then from the front end via chrom. Thank you again for your assistance friend.

Comment: Trying to figure out how it all fits together and where I should put your latest code. In the include.asp file or on the actually. be very gratefully have any advice. Thank you sir

Comment: In the include file, instead the loop you currently have

Comment: You are amazing Shadow wizard..Thank you so much for all your help!!!! Cant say thank you enough sir!!!